# Как создать экземпляр класса, чтобы он был экземпляром интерфейса?

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации

Хочу сделать свой вариант DI, чтобы, например, в классе SecondClass поля MyClass и MyClass2 инстанцировались автоматически при создании SecondClass. Проблемы возникают, когда то же самое я пытаюсь сделать для ThirdClass в котором класс SecondClass представлен как интерфейс SD2. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

```
package com.my;

public class SecondClass implements SD2 {

    @ConstructorObject
    private MyClass myClass;

    @ConstructorObject
    private MyClass2 myClass2;

    @Override
    public MyClass getMyClass() {
        return myClass;
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass2 getMyClass2() {
        return myClass2;
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.my;

public class MyClass {

    private String text = "Hello";


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.my;

    public class MyClass2 {

        private int number = 300;


        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }
    }
```

---

```
package com.my;

public class ThirdClass {

    @ConstructorObject
    private SD2 secondClass2;

    @ConstructorObject
    private MyClass2 myClass22;

    public SD2 getSecondClass2() {
        return secondClass2;
    }

    public MyClass2 getMyClass22() {
        return myClass22;
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.my;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test2 {

public static <T> T construct(Class<T> object) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException{
        Field[] fields = object.getDeclaredFields();
        T obj = object.newInstance();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            Annotation[] annotations = field.getAnnotations();
            for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                if (annotation instanceof ConstructorObject) {
                    Object object1;
                    if (field.getType().getName().startsWith("com.my")) {
                        object1 = Test2.construct(field.getType());
                    } else {
                        Class type2 = field.getType();
                        object1 = type2.newInstance();
                    }
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    field.set(obj, object1);
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException {
        SD2 secondClass = Test2.construct(SD2.class);
        ThirdClass thirdClass = Test2.construct(ThirdClass.class);
        System.out.println(secondClass.getMyClass().getText());
        System.out.println(secondClass.getMyClass2().getNumber());

        System.out.println(thirdClass.getSecondClass2().getMyClass().getText());
        System.out.println(thirdClass.getSecondClass2().getMyClass2().getNumber());
        System.out.println(thirdClass.getMyClass22().getNumber());
    }
```

Comment: В общем я нашёл два варианта. Либо брать пакет и пробегаться по всем классам в пакете и искать, который из них имплементирует данный интерфейс, либо пометить аннотацией интерфейс, а в аннотации хранить филд класса Class с нужным классом, который и будет инстанцироваться в данный интерфейс.